# Getting DecisionTableParseException in drools

Tags: java, drools

I am using drools decision table to emit DRL's.
Now, while parsing excel sheet getting this exception occasionally.
Interestingly drools is able to parse excel sheet but very next time it simple fails to recognize the format without doing any change in code or excel sheet.

(Problem may sound vague, but even I am not able to find any pattern in this)

```
org.drools.template.parser.DecisionTableParseException: Failed to open Excel stream, please check that the content is xls97 format.
        at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.parseFile(ExcelParser.java:94)
        at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:89)
        at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:68)
        at com.flipkart.inventory.regPlanning.workers.ItemRuleProcessor.init(ItemRuleProcessor.java:57)
```

Comment: Did you resolved it? I am getting same issue. In windows its working fine, but linux I am getting same error as yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrapper exception on an IOException:

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-decisiontables/src/main/java/org/drools/decisiontable/parser/xls/ExcelParser.java#L94

Check the root IOException for more information on the cause, but my guess is that you are having file access issues. Alternatively, check the JXL version you are using and make sure it is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check access thing. Btw JXL version is 2.6.10 and it's downloaded(using maven) by drools itself, so hoping version mismatch should not be there.